# Português Português ou Português Brasileiro?

Tags: suporte, edição, edições-sugeridas, diferenças-regionais

Ainda hoje, alguém sugeriu uma edição à uma resposta minha, e nos comentários de edição dizia simplesmente *"corre**c**ção do português"* ou algo semelhante, não lembro com clareza. Acontece que dos erros citados, nenhum era erro, porque estavam escritos em **pt-PT** que é o português que aprendi e cresci, mas foi sugerida uma edição, o editor, só não fez as alterações porque não dispunha de privilégios para tal.

Havia também 2 rejeições para essa mesma sugestão, e nos comentários diziam, que é correto porque é **pt-PT** e nada tem de errado.

Comumente escrevo em **pt-BR** porque o meu navegador aplica correções automaticamente, ou porque às vezes entra em conflito com a forma como digito as palavras e marca-as com vermelho, e acabo por me questionar se sou eu quem está errado ou o *humilde* corretor. Quando estou a escrever à partir de um navegador sem corretor automático para **pt-BR**, simplesmente escrevo, e foi o que aconteceu ontem.

Sabe-se que agora é **regra** para escrita, mas é realmente obrigatório fazer perguntas e dar respostas com base no **pt-BR**, sendo que ainda existe o **pt-PT** ?

Comment: Outra: ["Deveremos manter algum standard linguístico ou não?"](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3/215)

Comment: @Edilson resumindo podes escrever em pt_PT ou pt_BR não convêm é misturar senão fica uma salgalhada.

Comment: Esse `c` a mais por exemplo, não foi eliminado por aquele acordo ortográfico?

Comment: @rray pode-se escrever com AO ou sem AO convém é ser coerente, ou se escreve tudo sem AO pt_PT ou com AO pt_PT e igualmente para pt_BR.

Comment: Quando procurei por perguntas semelhantes, não encontrei nenhuma.

Comment: @Edilson é bom esta pergunta ficar também no site, alguém há-de procurar da mesma forma que tu escreveste a pergunta. As duplicatas são boas se bem feitas, que é o caso.

Comment: O primeiro parágrafo citado na outra pergunta, foi simplesmente esclarecedor.

Comment: Edilson o importante é manter o padrão de escrita. Como já comentado pelo @JorgeB.

Comment: Pois, vou é marcar esta como duplicada, caso alguém procure por _"português"_.